# Seeking Feedback on Code Optimizations: Flutter TextField Custom Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, controller, widget, components

I have a Flutter template, and then i want to change the widget only but many fitures not working example like this

```
                            Expanded(
                              child: DInput(
                                controller: edtUsername,
                                fillColor: Colors.white70,
                                hint: 'Username',
                                radius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                validator: (input) =>
                                    input == '' ? "Don't empty" : null,
                              ),
                            ),
```

i change the widget like this

```
              TextFieldName(controller: edtUsername,
                  validator: (value) {
                if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter your name';
                }
                return null;
              }),
```

TextFieldName

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TextFieldName extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final String? Function(String?) validator;

  const TextFieldName({
    Key? key,
    required this.controller,
    required this.validator,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 300,
      height: 40,
      decoration: ShapeDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
        ),
      ),
      child: TextField(
        controller: controller,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          prefixIcon: Container(
            width: 20,
            height: 20,
            child: Image.asset(
              'assets/icon/User.png',
              width: 20,
              height: 20,
            ),
          ),
          hintText: 'Enter your name',
          hintStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Color(0xFFA1A1A1),
            fontFamily: 'RobotoSlab',
            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
            fontSize: 12,
          ),
          contentPadding:
              EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

but the validator and controller not working, i've use many methods to fix that like import the validator from d_input but still not working

anybody can solve my problem

Comment: What does "not work" mean? What is the desired effect and what are you getting?

Comment: @Albert221 not work means the problem "Undefined name 'controller'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name." i have try to import from d_input.dart but still not nothing

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to use the TextFormField approach of validation in the TextField widget class by defining validator as `final String? Function(String?) validator;`

You could make the TextField into a TextFormField and add validation like so

```
   TextFormField(
    controller: controller,
    validator: validator,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      prefixIcon: Container(
        width: 20,
        height: 20,
        child: Image.asset(
          'assets/icon/User.png',
          width: 20,
          height: 20,
        ),
      ),
      hintText: 'Enter your name',
      hintStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Color(0xFFA1A1A1),
        fontFamily: 'RobotoSlab',
        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
        fontSize: 12,
      ),
      contentPadding:
          EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

**Note the addition of validator after the controller parameter on line 3**

Comment: i try that code too, but "Undefined name 'controller'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name." in my old template that import from d_input.dart but still that problem not fixed

Comment: @HollowX7 could you provide the code for the d_input.dart too? Or could you give clarity on these:: how many files are you working in??  and in which of the files is the TextController defined??  and in which of the files is the TextController being called??

If you are getting undefined name 'controller' then it means you are trying to call a 'controller' variable that's not yet defined or is out of scope.